# sqlite3 + sqlalchemy iterative database adding error - python (battling)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have 9 xlsx files I want to read data from and add each row into a table in a database.

Here is the code:

```
import sqlalchemy
import os
import csv
import sqlite3

from readData import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

#Change these
dbname = "TandWPODB2"

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()
filePath = "CAM MIKE DATA\B2B\TEMPLE AND WEBSTER PO"
purchDirectory = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(filePath))
print purchDirectory

class TandWPurchaseOrder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tandwpurchaseorder'

    orderNum = Column(Integer)
    barcode = Column(String)
    skuNum = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    shipID = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    quantity = Column(Integer)
    costPrice = Column(String)
    totalCost = Column(String)
    agreedDeliveryDate = Column(String)
    colour = Column(String)
    material = Column(String)
    itemDims = Column(String)
    CoO = Column(String)  # what even is this?
    itemWeightEa = Column(String)
    shipWidth = Column(String)
    shipDepth = Column(String)
    shipHeight = Column(String)
    itemCubic = Column(String)
    totalCubic = Column(String)
    deadweight = Column(String)


def createDB(dbname):
    global dbEngine
    global dbSession

    dbEngine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + dbname, echo=False)
    #create Session
    Session = sessionmaker()
    Session.configure(bind=dbEngine)
    dbSession = Session()

    #create tables
    Base.metadata.create_all(dbEngine)
    print "db created"


def readPurchaseOrder(purchDirectory, session):
    wsList = readFiles(purchDirectory)
    wsRange = []
    headers = []
    # print type(wsList) #List
    # print(type(wsList[0]))
    #for i,ws in enumerate(wsList):
    for ws in wsList:
        #print type(ws)
        list1, list2 = readWs(ws)  # list1 = wsRange, list2 = headers
        wsRange.append(list1)
        headers.append(list2)
        # print headers[0]
        # print (wsRange)
        #wsRange[i(ws)][j][k] = k item in row j of table/book i
    # print(len(wsRange)) #9 = num pages
    # print(len(wsRange[0])) #changing = num rows
    # print(len(wsRange[0][0])) #20 = num item in row


    # for i = len(wsRange)
    for i in range(len(wsRange)):
        for j in range(len(wsRange[i])):
            TandWPurchOrder = TandWPurchaseOrder(
                                                orderNum = wsRange[i][j][0].value,
                                                barcode = wsRange[i][j][1].value,
                                                skuNum = wsRange[i][j][2].value,
                                                shipID = wsRange[i][j][3].value,
                                                description = wsRange[i][j][4].value,
                                                quantity = wsRange[i][j][5].value,
                                                costPrice = wsRange[i][j][6].value,
                                                totalCost = wsRange[i][j][7].value,
                                                agreedDeliveryDate = wsRange[i][j][8].value,
                                                colour = wsRange[i][j][9].value,
                                                material = wsRange[i][j][10].value,
                                                itemDims = wsRange[i][j][11].value,
                                                CoO = wsRange[i][j][12].value,  # what even is this?
                                                itemWeightEa = wsRange[i][j][13].value,
                                                shipWidth = wsRange[i][j][14].value,
                                                shipDepth = wsRange[i][j][15].value,
                                                shipHeight = wsRange[i][j][16].value,
                                                itemCubic = wsRange[i][j][17].value,
                                                totalCubic = wsRange[i][j][18].value,
                                                deadweight = wsRange[i][j][19].value,
                                                )

            dbSession.add(TandWPurchOrder)
    dbSession.commit()


createDB(dbname)
Base.metadata.create_all(dbEngine)
readPurchaseOrder(purchDirectory, dbSession)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) column skuNum is not unique [SQL: u'INSERT INTO tandwpurchaseorder
```

I'm very new to python and databasing so any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: In the table column `skuNum` is primary key. So for every row it should have unique value. You could check if there are scenarios where the value for that column is same for two or more iterations

Comment: Ahh okay so the sku (stock keeping unit) will probably be the same for some rows if some purchases are of the same product. So you suggest I change what the primary key is?

Comment: You could change the primary key to some other column which is guaranteed to have unique value for every rows

Comment: That also leads to another problem as none of the columns have a unique value, even the order number just counts up in each excel file :/

Comment: Then you can create another column say `purchaseOrderId` which can be automatically inceremented for the rows and it will be guaranteed to have unique value. SQLite provides AUTOINCREMENT for this purpose

Comment: Thank you! I added a counter for the primary key and it works now :) Is it possible to move the class to another .py file and import it?